# fetch specific data from "file_get_contents"

Tags: fetch, file-get-contents

First of all, I'd like to notify everyone I'm very new at programming. To avoid uselessly long message, I'll jump right into my question:

In php code I use:

> $content = file_get_contents("https://website.com/contentId=445"); //this is just an example link

and my question is: how can I fetch two values (Value #1 and Value #2) that follows in the $content output so I could use them later in my code as (for example) $fetchedvalue1 and $fetchedvalue2?

```
<span id="the_span_id1" class="">Value #1:</span>
                                <strong>
                                    <span class="price">
                                        999.11&nbsp;USD 
                                    </span>
                                </strong>
                                <br/>
                                <span id="the_span_id2" class="">Value #2:</span>
                                <span class="price">
                                    111.11&nbsp;USD
                                </span>
```

Tried to google for hours, but without any results - I found several similar questions but couldn't make their code to work in this environment.
Please let me know if anything is left unclear in this question.

Any advice is highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could use Regular Expression to handle this or you could also try some HTML parser as a more sophisticated solution.

I found this question that has some content related to HTML parsing: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

If you don't know regular expressions I found this pretty quickly: [Regular expressions - An introduction](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/regex.html) but don't settle with this one and try to find some guide that better fits your needs. It may seem complicated at first but soon you'll learn, and having some text/tutorial that better connects with your way of learning is key.

You could also use a more rough approach that consists of a series `str_replace` and/or `explode` and clean the parts you don't need.